# Andengine 2d side-scrolling character movement

Tags: android, andengine

I have a script here:

```java
final FixtureDef characterfictur = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.5f, 0.1f,0.1f); // Maybe other fixture?

this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);

final Body body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, charactersprite, BodyType.DynamicBody, characterfictur);

this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(charactersprite, body, true, false));
mScene.attachChild(charactersprite);

createUnwalkableObjects(mTMXTiledMap);
// HUD
HUD my = new HUD();
Sprite forward = new Sprite( 50, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 170, forwardr) {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY) {
        if(!pEvent.isActionUp()) {
            charactersprite.getTextureRegion().setFlippedHorizontal(false);
            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(CHAR_MOVING_SPEED,body.getLinearVelocity().y)); // Velocity
            //body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(2,0), body.getPosition());
        } else {
            //body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0,0), body.getPosition());
            body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(0,body.getLinearVelocity().y)); // LinearVelocity
        }
        return false;

    }
};
```

and little forward :

```java
private void createUnwalkableObjects(TMXTiledMap map) {
// Loop through the object groups

    for(final TMXObjectGroup group: map.getTMXObjectGroups()) {

        //if(group.getTMXObjectGroupProperties().containsTMXProperty("Zeme", "true")){
            // This is our "wall" layer. Create the boxes from it

        for(final TMXObject object : group.getTMXObjects()) {

            final Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(object.getX(), object.getY(),object.getWidth(), object.getHeight());
            final FixtureDef boxFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0,3f);
            PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, rect, BodyType.StaticBody, boxFixtureDef);
            rect.setVisible(false);
            mScene.attachChild(rect);
        }
        //}
    }
}
```

So, when i move the character it moves very weird. It gitters when walks. So, maybe i need to change fixtures, or use other moving method?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a fixedPhysicsWorld and a fixedStepEngine. That will get rid of the 'jitters' Also when the level first starts you might want to have a "Ready!" prompt that waits a few seconds to let the physics engine ramp up as it tends to start out a little slow then speeds up.